# What is the maximum length of a facebook name?

Tags: facebook

What is the maximum length of a facebook name, the one you get in the parameter "name" from the graph API.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Maximum length of a Facebook username is currently 50 characters.

While trying to create a "really long name" as @BK suggested, the Facebook user account view complains with anything of 51 characters or greater:

[image: Facebook user account view complaining when a 51 character username is provided - "Max length exceeded"]

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer Is a Facebook account required to access that page?

Answer (score 14):

I'm pretty sure that its not documented anywhere, but my guess would be 50 as the longest one I've seen after looking over several hundred thousand users is 49.

Ron Bowes posted a [torrent](http://www.skullsecurity.org/blogdata/fbdata.torrent) with over [100 million Facebook user names](http://www.skullsecurity.org/blog/2010/return-of-the-facebook-snatchers).  You could pull that down and query it if you really wanted to know.  Or try creating a Facebook account with a really long name.

Comment: i can also verify 50 as maximum. checked over 100k pages and around 10 of them used 50 character long usernames without any special characters. so varchar(50) is the way to go. unicode is not needed here due to character limitations in the username by facebook.

Answer (score -1):

I recently encountered a unicode name (first & last name combined) that exceeded 255 bytes, unfortunately I don't recall how many characters specifically, but it broke our `varchar(255)` database field.

Comment: Did you mean the name or the username?

Comment: Well, I couldn't recall why did I ask this :) Anyway, was it longer than 255 chars or 255 bytes? If it's shorter than or equal to 255 (unicode) chars it should fit in an utf8 encoded `varchar(255)` field even if it's longer than 255 bytes. Otherwise it would mean that Facebook is storing names in `text` or something, which would be interesting.